# Is the [date] tag useful?

Tags: discussion, tags

We've got a few dozen questions tagged with [date](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date).

To me, this is not a useful tag.

Who's an expert on dates? Who is going to follow this tag?

A tag should be able to describe a question all by itself. Those tagged with "date" run the gamut from how to format a date value (in a number of different apps) to how to search by date, to filtering by date range.

Before I went on a cleanup spree, I wanted to get opinions from the rest of the community.

Comment: As half of the those tags are used for Google Spreadsheets, I'm there to follow. Expert on dates, no, that's Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 2):

From the list of questions we have it seems to me that it should be half of a compound tag something like [date-entry](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date-entry) or [date-format](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date-format).

I also note a [data](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data) tag and a [hide](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hide) tag. Neither of which seem to be that useful either.

Comment: I'll see if I can clean up "date" with "date-format" and see what's left.

Answer (score -2):

Somebody took the liberty of creating a wiki text for that tag, quite recently.

That, for me, justifies the existence of the tag.

Comment: That's a pretty weak justification to keep a tag. I could just as easily write a very nice tag wiki on [tag:muffins], but that wouldn't make it any more on-topic or useful.